# Change HTTP status code for TYPO3 shortcut and external URL pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I`m sure that I`ve seen a screenshot or live-Backend where the edit-page dialogue featured an select-box to change the HTTP status code for page-types "shortcut" or "external URL".

So the editor was able to select "301 redirect" for shortcut-pages. For some reason I thought this is a TYPO3 8 feature but that seems to be false assumption.

Anyways, I`d like to have that feature or as an alternative would like to be able to change all redirects for "shortcut" or "external URL" pages to 301 by default. How can I do this with TYPO3 8?

Comment: I guess that it's this issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/73139

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/73139 you currently need an extension to accomplish it: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/shortcut_statuscodes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Riccardo De Contardi . Will have a look at this extensions/manuals:

```
https://github.com/patrickbroens/TYPO3.UrlForwarding
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/shortcut_statuscodes/
http://www.typo3manual.com/typo3-version-8/10-301-redirects/
```